# How to know if there is a change in the table?

Tags: java, sql-server, events, triggers

We have a PLM system where users go and create/update objects (i.e. Products, Colorway etc...). This objects eventually gets stored to sqlserver database. The tables do have a column for modifyTimeStamp. The field has updated timestamp when a user updated an object.

We are integrating this tool with some other application. This other application needs to know when someone creates/update objects to our PLM System.

What's the best way to achieve this? Writing some kind of listener which will keep listening and if there is a change in the table, it will notify?

The other approach could be having a trigger. But, then how my code will call that trigger as the triggers are only within the scope of that table?

Comment: trigger are fired when there is a `insert` , `update` or `delete` on the table. It can't be `called` by any application / code

Comment: Correct. What's the other approach to achieve my requirements?

Comment: Actually there is a type of trigger that you can use for this... It's called DDL trigger and as the name implies, they fire based on DDL changes.

Comment: Create a flag file when any update happen in table, keep checking that flag file from other application, if found delete it and read new data.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to go about to solve this problem. I will try to describe a few.

1. Creating a scheduler on the listening application. I suggest to implement a scheduler that will run every given interval to fetch the latest data according to the modify time and processing them.
2. Creating a new API on the listening application and to call it via the creating/updating application.
3. Using a microservice architecture such as using messaging services between the applications to inform one or another of creation/update events.

I hope it will help you and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a feature called "[Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)". It must first be activated for a database. If it is activated, you can issue special queries that return information about data changes in a specific table.

According to the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the query

```
DECLARE @last_sync_version bigint;  
SET @last_sync_version = <value obtained from query>;  
SELECT [Emp ID], SSN,  
    SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,  
    SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT   
FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES Employees, @last_sync_version) AS C;
```

would return the data changes in the `Employees` table since `@last_sync_version`.